# ignore extra spaces when using fgets

Tags: c, fgets

I'm using fgets with stdin to read in some data, with the max length I read in being 25. With one of the tests I'm running on this code, there are a few hundred spaces after the data that I want - which causes the program to fail.

Can someone advise me as to how to ignore all of these extra spaces when using fgets and go to the next line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fgets()` iteratively, then scan the string to see whether it is all spaces (and whether it ends with a newline) and ignore it if it is.  Or use `getc()` or `getchar()` in a loop instead?

```
char buffer[26];

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
{
    ...process the first 25 characters...
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        ;
}
```

That code simply ignores all characters up to the next newline.  If you want to ensure that they are spaces, add a test in the (inner) loop - but you have to decide what to do if the character is not a space.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to use getchar() ignore all of the whitespace. I've tried just doing:

while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && (int)ch != EOF );

but that caused an infinite loop

Comment: Note that I declared `c` as an `int` and not as a `char`; I also tested for EOF before newline, though it will work the other way round if you assign to an `int` and not to a `char`.  Remember, the functions (macros) `getc()` and `getchar()` return an INTEGER, not a `char`.  Anything you are told three times is true.

Answer (score 0):

Spelling out the suggestion given by Jonathan Leffler about getc():

I assume you have a loop like this:

```
while (!feof(stdin)) {
  fgets(buf, 25, stdin);
  ...
}
```

change it like this:

```
while (!feof(stdin)) {
  int read = fgets(buf, 27, stdin);
  if (read > 26) { // the line was *at least* as long as the buffer
    while ('\n' != getc()); // discard everything until the newline character
  }
  ...
}
```

Edit: Ah, Jonathan is faster than I am at writing C.  :)

Comment: Remember that `getc()` needs a file pointer (presumably stdin given the question), but `getchar()` assumes stdin.  And beware EOF - your inner loop won't stop if there is no remaining newline in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , for removing trailing spaces.

```
 char str[100] ;
    int i ;
    fgets ( str , 80 , stdin ) ;
    for ( i=strlen(str) ; i>0 ; i-- )
    {
            if ( str[i] != ' ' )
            {
                    str[i+1]='\0';
                    break ;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Use 'sizeof(str)' in preference to 80.